# Exception when inserting DBNull in SQL Image column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to insert NULL in SQL Image column if BinaryImage value is null.

This is the problematic part of the code:

```
SqlParameter[] dsUpdateFarmacevtiParams = new SqlParameter[32];
if (img.Value != null)
{
    dsUpdateFarmacevtiParams[31] = new SqlParameter("@img", img.Value);
}
else
{
    dsUpdateFarmacevtiParams[31] = new SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.Image);
    dsUpdateFarmacevtiParams[31].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

When the if statement is true everything is okay, but when img.value is null I'm getting this error:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image

My question is, how to pass DBNull to SQL Image column in this situation?

Comment: The error message suggests this have nothing to do with DBNull... try changing the parameter type to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`

Comment: Cannot reproduce that problem. There is no issue creating a paramenter of type SqlDbType.Image and then setting its value to DbNull.Value. Where do you get the error? In these lines or when you try to execute the query? Are you executing a stored procedure that expects a different type for the 32 parameter?

Comment: BTW, the image datatype has been deprecated for more than a decade now in favor of varbinary(max).

Comment: @Steve 

I'm getting the error when executing the stored procedure, on line 40 (see the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/inao0y))

Comment: @SeanLange I know, but I'm working on an existing application, I'm trying to get this solved without changing the database. Thank you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Nope, that will not solve the problem. The nvarchar in this situation is DBNull, so SQL is not accepting nvarchar for a column of type Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, guys, I've solved the problem. I've modified the procedure and set a **default NULL value to the parameter** like this @img image = NULL. 
That was easy, but I've lost 5 hours on this :)